# Typescript access class members from methods without this keyword

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop

I am quite new to Node and TypeScript, but was surprised that you must specify `this` to access class members when implementing classes. For example:

```
class MyClass {
  private value: string

  constructor(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }
    
  getSomething() { return this.value }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of `this` in `getSomething` method?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't wanna use `this` keyword?

Comment: Yes, I think we need to hear about the underlying use case.  Right now it would seem the cure is worse than the disease, unless I'm missing something about the disease.

Comment: You have to specify `this` because unlike languages like Java or C# there *is* a top level that you can use. In Java/C# `this.foo` and `foo` can't lead to two different properties on the object. In JS/TS `this.foo` would access the property `foo` on whatever `this` happens to be (object instance in classes usually) but `foo` will crawl the scope to find an identifier called `foo`. These are almost never going to be the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I have programmed in other languages where it is not mandatory: Java, C#, C++. I just read a similar post about Python. The main issue is that `value = 123` is uncertain whether it is just an assignment or also declares a variable. However, new JavaScript does not really have this issue: `assignment to undeclared variable value`.

Comment: "*The main issue is that value = 123 is uncertain whether it is just an assignment or also declares a variable*" you'd get a compilation error for assigning to an undeclared identifier. It'd be quite clear. And as you mention in strict mode that's also a runtime error. All code in classes (any ES6+ constructs with a code block, really) will automatically run code inside in strict mode without requiring to opt in with a directive.

Comment: I'm still trying to comprehend the use case. Surely it isn't just that other languages do things differently, is it?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that makes sense. In the worst case scenario, it could end up accessing a `value` variable that you may not expect, in case you forgot to declare it at the class level. However, that is not really a problem when using TypeScript from Node.js, because it is modular and the global scope is limited. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Even if there is a name clash between a property and another identifier in the scope chain, chances are that the *types* would be different. So if you tried `value = 123` you'd likely still get a compilation error saying you are assigning a number to something that's not a number.

Comment: @jcalz The use case is typing and reading less characters :) However, I understand that there could be problems if the TypeScript code is written outside Node modules (pure frontend with TypeScript compiler). Should I remove this question? I think it is useful for people surprised about the same thing.

Comment: The question is fine but given your use case the correct answer is probably "please don't try to do that, you will make things much worse for yourself."  Imagine I asked "how can I return the final expression from a function without writing the `return` keyword? My use case is writing fewer characters, and language X allows it." Wouldn't the only responsible answer be "please don't try to do that" and not "here's a convoluted thing involving arrow functions, code generation, and unicorn blood"?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, it's funny how you put it :) Can you provide a clear answer with these thoughts so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments provided so far within this post, although the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77846528/2109230) provides a way of automating class implementation without using `this` keyword, this is not a recommended practice.

The bottom line is that it is not possible to know whether or not using a variable declared in parent context relative to the class implementation is intended or accidental. In addition, enforcing class only member access would break existing code.

However, I still think this can be made a TypeScript feature to be used on new projects (class context only). In case it is turned off accidentally, a lot of code would no longer compile due to missing `this` when accessing members. Existing code should compile fine since `this` is redundant. So, it should be safe to use such a feature.

Answer (score -1):

Putting aside that removing `this` would make it impossible to access global variables with the same name, here is how to avoid using `this` when implementing classes:

```
function newMyClass(value: string) {
  function getSomething() { return value }

  // Return members that are supposed to be public.
  return {
    getSomething
  }
}


class MyClass {
  private internal: ReturnType<typeof newMyClass>
  getSomething: typeof this.internal.getSomething

  constructor(value: string) {
    this.internal = newMyClass(value)
    Object.assign(this, this.internal)
  }
}

console.log(new MyClass("abc").getSomething());
```

You can test this code here: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGApgdwLIE8DCAbAQwGciAKANwLxBQC5EioAnGMAcwEpEBvAKEUShIsBIjYooAZTgBbCQAtWbUl26ImEkEySVqKRAF9e-dZu08TA8VNkKlJo0eMRCJRNnzEiFgQAcWlFD6rEHaVPQASmZgACpYvigAPFDxKHDAyOgerkQAfCbW0nJQiuz0KQnpiCUwRAB0IShheHWFtjXsxgIQCIxMINBwTBRUNPR9SqqW1Yr1jc2IALyZmLg5I3oc0wDyAEYAVijQdV4wbGCkNUQANDO1DWChYFRbAo7OvXB4KHV4cMqoNDuNZeUgAIgIuwgYI4rQkRTs7BUHAA3EA). The only downside is having a false error: Property 'getSomething' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Loosing access to global variables with the same name should not be a problem in Node.js, because they are global at the module level. Global variables from other modules can be renamed when importing them:

`import { value as module1Value } from './module1'`

I also did a benchmark with numbers instead of string. The results are either similar or one of them is way faster than the other. Here is the benchmark code: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATBmFcDsGMBcEsD2liQKYHcCyBPAwgDYCGAziQBQBuRB4aAXKuALYBGaATgJTADeAsACgQEGAmTAA5mlgBlRMxkALeJEnkeA4SGAcZ4Dimq00AbiEgAvkIu79hvrZDS5C5askAaW5fODrgkLQxGTAuISkJI7aAA4c8NSwaMCqSYY0jABK9pAAKjgxaAA8sAVoiKComOEhJAB8fs4y8oqwKmqMpYUVwG3wJAB0qZyQNAMuLe5qfrbQyCSwHOBwiBxUNHSMkCzs3NE6vSqDw%20kEwAC8Vdj4tesmXI06APKsAFZocAOR8JKQ5H0kTyHfpDSBpUYEB4%20IQBIK1MI3SIAJn2wDiCSISWAxk2TDYnBm2jmkAWSxWaxxDDxu00TmBg0pF2xGzM0MC2gmbj6ag0qJAelgBhQAIGlMeAQCIFm81gKTSmKQJKZAEYAAzqjWPYkLYDMIgADwAaiyVQB9DXm9VamXMkxRS4AbQGzvQGGAAEEOBwiDhyPB5eISVwALoDPUxch%202A8c51MKYpQDUAERCrchYBMDb2QAAmCl5ACpdQbjfcoeyRFA4IrgOwYEo9RwANbkUaKRikjxApREXMETiMKNbHacGNx7b4vZaA792WgVbQNAAUWMTNVjxAs%20ACyIHFguXgiiZhQ4844epgaAGkEQGA0G9tdEGZ6XRGgSkj-rHwHIZ8XK5oYAAD1Lh7PtOCjLgoIfLc0FzA8j0uE8zwvRdr1ve8bG0fkcmAAADAASXg2zQSxGCIuCcwQ5IAFpt1gXd90PUjgAAHzsEhwAIWByN4P9l2MSw8PFLDNxkDiuNgZUmTrd9GxbAByHdc13HMFKBSCLnHTAEQiMhIPGZouXadRoNsLc9E47iUUuWSG13RS4kQGJEBINA1I0r8tKuXTbi-QzXFaEyNHLWwAHowuAXJEGLJtkk4vRDk4ZJ%20lQGLQHgDgdQQI85mYGJwAYwNgBzfpoHiZhVAVZABlsSzJOk2y4LkhzyCUhiVI4Dyfy82MfJqSIDM5IKPBCx56usmTmvs5s2qcly3O6zS%20tdXzBv84aplM0KiXmRB%20wGFN1AmqTyxAbV9qvI7yBOpEHiAA)

Comment: So, you want to avoid adding five characters. To do that, you've decided to jump through several hoops and add a lot more code than you saved up. And introduced flaky code to barely duct tape what you want to do together. What exactly is the benefit of any of that?

Comment: I don't see the point of even having a class anymore if you're doing that. Just use your `newMyClass` function with its closure... dressing up `newMyClass` in `class` clothing only really serves to confuse things; you'll have all kinds of "interesting" behavior if people treat it like a regular class (what happens if someone subclasses it or tries looking at its prototype, etc).  What is the actual use case for this?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, you have a good point there. It's not something standard to do. However, I think I could get away with that code simply getting transpiled from the original code in the post. I also think there should be no problem with inheritance.

Comment: @VLAZ In this particular example it is not really useful, but the point is that those five characters are repeated many times over complex code. I find it specially annoying when writing code like `this.balance = this.balance * (1 + this.interest) * (1 - this.fee)`, which I would have prefered to look like `balance = balance * (1 + interest) * (1 - fee)`.

Comment: @MatrixRonny Use destructuring then: `let { balance, interest, fee } = this`.

Comment: @InSync I think this is going in the right direction to what I want. I am aiming for simplifying complex code, with many occurrences  of `this`.

Comment: I would be okay with destructuring if it  had support for passing by reference. Without that, you still need `this` when assigning members. This is not intuitive and is prone to errors.